# Decode JSON in Bash using python mjson.tool

Tags: python, json, bash, grep

I need to get a `key` from JSON in standard bash, and found the following:

```
echo '{"first_key": "value", "second_key": "value2"}' | python -mjson.tool | grep 'first_key'
```

But this returns:

```
"first_key": "value",
```

How can I just return `value`, i.e. not the key, and remove the quotes and comma.

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
$ echo '{"first_key": "value", "second_key": "value2"}' | python -c 'import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)[sys.argv[1]])' first_key
value
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged it `grep` here is a solution for that (though [Ignacio's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17375969/970195) solution is the right way to do it):

```
echo "..." | grep -oP "(?<=\"first_key\": \")[^\"]+"
```

**Output:**

```
$ echo '{"first_key": "value", "second_key": "value2"}' | grep -oP "(?<=\"first_key\": \")[^\"]+"
value
```

Comment: Note: `GNU grep` and latter `OSX grep` only.